# Cannot log to /var/log/messages via Python 3.6.4

Tags: python-3.x, syslog

```
/opt/python/bin/python -c "if True:
    import logging
    import logging.handlers
    logger = logging.getLogger('example')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    syslog_handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler()
    syslog_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(syslog_handler)
    logger.critical('Hello world')
"
```

No error, but nothing appears in /var/log/messages.

Answer (score 0):

The answer:

```
syslog_handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler("/dev/log")
```

`/dev/log` is a unix socket, more details [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Overview-of-Syslog.html).

Note that on my RHEL system at the office this writes to `/var/log/messages`.  At home on Ubuntu it writes to `/var/log/syslog`.